# How update project version in package.json (with vue cli)

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

this should be very simple but it's hard to google for me because everything I've found was about updating NPM version or dependencies etc. - not a thing about simply change the project version in package.json.

I am using Vue CLI on vue2 project and I just need to update version in `package.json`.
Problem is that when I just rewrite it (like from `'0.1'` to `'0.2'`), Vue CLI won't compile the project because package-lock.json

Error:

```
Error: Invalid version: "0.2"
 ... bla bla ...
```

PS: my thoughts was like: revrite version like `'0.1' -> '0.2'`, then `npm i` (install) should update package lock. Then everything should be ok. Well, it's not and it's much more ungoogleable than I thought :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [answer](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#version)

I've lied a little, the change was from `0.1.0` -> `0.1`
And they stated that the version number MUST be

> parseable by node-semver

So I've tried `0.1.1` and now it's ok.